# Bash script to check if a number is a multiple of 3, 5 or both

Tags: bash, math

The variable D is supposed to contain a positive integer. My FizzBuzz program has to use arithmetic substitution and the ||, &&, () operators. If the number is a multiple of three, the program should output the word Fizz; if the number is a multiple of five, the word Buzz. If the number is a multiple of three and five, then the program should display the word FizzBuzz. I am a novice programmer, unsure where I have gone wrong.

"""

```
#!/bin/bash

D=5
if [ $D % 3 == 0 ] ;
then
echo "Fizz"
elif [[ $D % 5 == 0 ]]
then
echo "Buzz"
elif [[ $D % 3 == 0 && $D % 5 == 0 ]]
fi
echo "FizzBuzz"
done
```

"""

Comment: Concerning your logic: it would not be possible to satisfy the `FizzBuzz` case as both those conditions are previously checked.  I would suggest checking the `FizzBuzz` first.  Plus your `fi` seems misplaced.

Comment: This question belongs on [codegolf.se].

Comment: In bash there's a difference between `==` and `-eq`; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120235 for more info

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform computations I recommend `((` and `))`:

```
#!/bin/bash

d=5

if (( $d%3 == 0 && $d%5 == 0 )); then
  echo "FizzBuzz";
else
  if (( $d%3 == 0 )); then
    echo "Fizz"
  elif (( $d%5 == 0 )); then
    echo "Buzz"
  fi
fi
```